# How to resize the colorbar to be the same height as an imagesc plot

Tags: matlab

I have multiple files where I plot some images of different sizes and then have a colorbar next to it. I have noticed that the colorbar size changes drastically as I resize the plotting window. I would like to save these figures such that the colorbars always have the same height as the image and a consistent width no matter the dimensions (in this example [60, 100] is used).

```
slice = flip(reshape(data, [60, 100]),1);
fig = imagesc(slice);
colorbar;
colormap jet;
axis equal
axis off
caxis([-0.1 1]);  
ticks = -0.1:0.1:1;  
cb = colorbar('Ticks', ticks); 
% Get positions of the image axes and colorbar
axPos = get(gca, 'Position');
cbPos = get(cb, 'Position');

% Resize colorbar height
cbPos(4) = axPos(4); % Match colorbar height to image height
set(cb, 'Position', cbPos);
```

Unfortunately, the code above does not correctly resize the colorbar. Can you help me edit the code to get the desired dimensions?

Comment: Hey there! Could you give us a minimal reproducible example please?

Comment: this works for me: replace `axis equal` with `axis equal tight`. then you dont need to do anything else i.e. you can remove the last 2 lines ! (PS delete the `axis off` line to see how it affects your graphs)